# Bootstrap Themes in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, themes

I want to implement a bootstrap theme for a website I created a while ago. I was looking to use the basic theme from here: https://startbootstrap.com/theme/freelancer

I have been reading many articles and watching videos but still cannot seem to get this to work. Could anyone provide me with a detailed step by step explanation on how to add a simple Bootstrap theme to and Ruby on Rails app that is already created? Or is that too much? Some of the videos I watched had me changing so many routes and copying and pasting many different things and I keep going wrong some where and don't know what else to try :/

Comment: Hi, since the question is very generic, I will leave this link to the article in case you are still trying: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-a-ruby-on-rails-application. Also, welcome to SO :)

Comment: Also, this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask